# Ways to synchronize lazy scheme with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, lazy-evaluation

I have a lazy scheme where I have following code:

```
 class C
 {
     foo(); //for every object C foo() (read/write) has to be called once before any bar()
     bar(); //bar is read only and completely threadsafe
     was_foo_already_called(); // true if any thread already called foo()
     was_foo_already_finished(); // true if any thread already called and finished foo()

     int ID; //class has members (is not empty)
 }


 ...

 const int large_number = 100;
 vector<C> vec (1000);

 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i < large_number ; i++) {
       int x = unknown_number_between_0_and_999( i ); //unforseeable index for vec

       C& obj = vec.at(x);

       if ( obj.was_foo_already_finished() ) {

            obj.bar(); // (Case 1)  quick and threadsafe

       } else if ( obj.was_foo_already_called() ) {

            (...) // (Case 2) needs to be blocked somehow
            obj.bar();

       } else {

            obj.foo(); // (Case 3)
            obj.bar();

       }
 }
```

Case 3 is fine by itself (as long as both boolean tests utilize synchronization, for example with scoped locking), as is Case 1.

Now my problem is Case 2. Even if I use scoped locking to only lock one instance of C, and case 2 gets blocked as long as `was_foo_already_finished()` returns false, it still blocks all threads with that x except one, leaving only 1 core active in the worst case scenario.

I need an implementation where those other "free" cores just continue with the next for-iteration (returning to their abandoned earlier iteration some time later, when `foo()` has hopefully been finished).

Is there maybe an implicit feature like this in OpenMP which I'm just overseeing?

PS: My entire code does not contain any specific synchronization tools provided by OpenMP, which is another (smaller) part of the question: How do I best synchronize those code parts?

Comment: If a thread can grab another value of `x` rather than wait then I assume you can fill an array with the values of x which will be used and how many times. Do that first then loop over that array (with 100 entries) using dynamic scheduling.

Comment: @Zboson This is a good and simple solution for the problem at hand, but we can't always split code into two loops like that (legacy code for example). Another reason: It does not work if the for loop has an indeterminate length (or the number of iterations changes while executing the code). Great solution, but not for all applications.

Comment: You have another serious problem with your code that makes fixing this problem useless. Suppose 2 Threads (T1 and T2) (using T# c# for "T# checks for case#"): T1 c1 -> false; T1 c2 -> false; T1 gets suspended; T2 c1-> false; T2 c2-> false;; now both Threads call foo even if locking is done correctly; so maybe you want to distribute this problem to the class itself where you can perform the checks inside of a secure environment